# Almost exact template

Tags: templates

(Sorry for this novice question)

I would like to (TeX)-Type:

[image]

[image]

What would be the mots exact template to (TeX-)typing it (based on the pages) included Title, affiliation, year, the space of the beginning of the paragraph and so on?

Comment: Do you want to **mimic** an **old typewriter**? If not, then I don't get the question.

Comment: I just want to mimic its structure exactly as possible.

Comment: The structure is paragraphs with an indention? Just start with an basic article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be a decent start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{\ttfamily - \thepage{} -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{.../...}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \ttfamily\raggedright
  \settowidth{\parindent}{xxxxxxxxxx}% 10 characters
}

\newcommand{\blskp}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}

% Header -----------------------------------------
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{-3em}}c@{}}
  SOME UNIVERSITY TITLE \\
  DEPARTMENT NAME \\
  MATHEMATICS
\end{tabular}\hspace{10em}%
Some University 1978-79

\bigskip

% Title -----------------------------------------
\begin{center}
  THIS IS A TITLE OF SORTS \\
  This is some subtitle description with a reference date 1978/79
\end{center}

% Body -----------------------------------------

\lipsum[1]

\blskp

\lipsum[2-3]

\blskp

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

- The headers/footers are set using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). First page has a different page style to accommodate for the `.../...` in the lower-right footer.
- [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) adjusts the page layout. Modify to suit your needs.
- There seems to be inconsistent paragraph gaps. So I've used `\bigskip` or `\blskp` (a vertical `\baselineskip`) to increase it where needed.
- The paragraph indentation is exactly 10 characters (under `\ttfamily`, or `typewriter`).
- Using `center` for the header of the document is not absolutely correct, since a default typewriter would horizontally align all characters in the monospace font. That is, the centering was most likely done manually using spaces. However, it's not all that visible in the layout, so maybe no-one will notice.

Comment: Many thanks, it is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help for a start?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{-- \thepage{} --}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\blindtext

\section{Section Title}
\blindtext

\section{Section Title}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]